# How to dynamically create multiple arrays [5,5] , and fill them with random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

How to create and fill multiple arrays [5,5], and print it to console.

for now i have that, but i cant get how to dynamically create arrays.
incoming value - for example 3, its mean to create 3 arrays 
and fill them with random values

```
            int n = 5;

            int count_array = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            int[,] arr = new int[n, n];


            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (var j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    ---
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that?

```
        int n = 5;

        int count_array = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,,] arr = new int[count_array, n, n];

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int current_array = 0; current_array < count_array; current_array++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Populating array #{current_array}:");

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    int value = rnd.Next();
                    arr[current_array, i, j] = value;
                    Console.Write(value+(j==n-1?"\r\n":","));
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: yes, it seems like that.
is it like an array from an arrays or what?)
some kind of 3d array?: D

Comment: exactly, its a 3-dimensional array - there are plenty other ways to solve it though